# Firebase event parameter confusion

Tags: android, firebase, google-analytics-firebase

I am trying to add the `add_to_cart` event to my Android app. The [Firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/analytics/FirebaseAnalytics.Event#ADD_TO_CART) says I should pass the following:

- `currency`
- `items` (as an array)
- `value`

However when I check the debug view I do see the `add_to_cart` event but no `items` array.

When I pass these parameters:

- `item_id`
- `currency`
- `price`
- `value`

I do see them in the debug view and can see a list of 'most added' products on my dashboard (but with no price data). Suggesting the data is at least somewhat valid.

So how should I implement the `add_to_cart` event? Which parameters should I use?

Comment: I also tried their default example of items but it did not work.
Did it finally work for you? @Mathyn

Comment: @techblu3 so far I have not been able to get a clear answer. I've chosen to stick with using `item_id` and not use the `items` array because with `item_id` I at least see a list of popular products.